# Image detection optimization

Tags: c#

I'm writing a script to automate the boring parts of a game. Essentially, I have a check boxes for different parts of the game that multiple players can use. If a checkbox its ticked then the script takes a screenshot and then if the location is available, my character is able to click the location and hops on this particular location before another player can, which looks like figure1.

Now, I have at most 18 possible locations my character can access (as long as another character is not already there.) If I have all 18 of the boxes checked, then my script will start running through all 18 of these locations until it finds an open one. Which is represented by basically a copy/paste of figure1 but adjusted in figure2.

I have a timer that kicks off every 5 seconds that checks to see if the screen has changed to check if it needs to take action. While, its not using a huge amount of CPU/memory sometimes it stops responding which isnt good. Also, every 5 seconds (which is when its performing screen checks) the power usage jumps to Very High. How can I optimize this so its more efficient? Are there better ways to check for screen changes?

**--figure1--**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //reference picture in resource folder
   ImageName = new LockBitmap(Properties.Resources.ImageName);
   ImageName.LockBits();

  //ImageDetection
private LockBitmap ImageName;
    private void RunImageName()
    {
        var handle = GetWindowsHandle();
        using (var screenshot = new LockBitmap(CaptureClient(handle)))
        {

            screenshot.LockBits();
            //Extensions menthod
            //screenshot.DoesImageExist(playbutton);
            var location = screenshot.GetFirstLocation(ImageName);

            if (location != Point.Empty)
            {
                var topleft = GetProcessWindowPoint(handle);
                var clickpoint = new Point(topleft.X + location.X, topleft.Y + location.Y);
                User32.SetCursorPos(clickpoint.X, clickpoint.Y);
                User32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                User32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            }
        }
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Argument
   if (ImageName01.Checked)
        {
            RunImageName();
            RunImageNameIcon();
        }
}
```

**--figure2--**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

 //reference picture in resource folder
ImageName1 = new LockBitmap(Properties.Resources.ImageName1);
ImageName1.LockBits();
ImageName2 = new LockBitmap(Properties.Resources.ImageName2);
ImageName2.LockBits();
ImageName3 = new LockBitmap(Properties.Resources.ImageName3);
ImageName3.LockBits();
}
//ImageDetection

private LockBitmap ImageName1;
    private void RunImageName1()
    {
        var handle = GetWindowsHandle();
        using (var screenshot = new LockBitmap(CaptureClient(handle)))
        {

            screenshot.LockBits();
            //Extensions menthod
            //screenshot.DoesImageExist(playbutton);
            var location = screenshot.GetFirstLocation(ImageName1);

            if (location != Point.Empty)
            {
                var topleft = GetProcessWindowPoint(handle);
                var clickpoint = new Point(topleft.X + location.X, topleft.Y + location.Y);
                User32.SetCursorPos(clickpoint.X, clickpoint.Y);
                User32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                User32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            }
        }
    }

private LockBitmap ImageName2;
    private void RunImageName2()
    {
        var handle = GetWindowsHandle();
        using (var screenshot = new LockBitmap(CaptureClient(handle)))
        {

            screenshot.LockBits();
            //Extensions menthod
            //screenshot.DoesImageExist(playbutton);
            var location = screenshot.GetFirstLocation(ImageName2);

            if (location != Point.Empty)
            {
                var topleft = GetProcessWindowPoint(handle);
                var clickpoint = new Point(topleft.X + location.X, topleft.Y + location.Y);
                User32.SetCursorPos(clickpoint.X, clickpoint.Y);
                User32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                User32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            }
        }
    }

private LockBitmap ImageName3;
    private void RunImageName3()
    {
        var handle = GetWindowsHandle();
        using (var screenshot = new LockBitmap(CaptureClient(handle)))
        {

            screenshot.LockBits();
            //Extensions menthod
            //screenshot.DoesImageExist(playbutton);
            var location = screenshot.GetFirstLocation(ImageName3);

            if (location != Point.Empty)
            {
                var topleft = GetProcessWindowPoint(handle);
                var clickpoint = new Point(topleft.X + location.X, topleft.Y + location.Y);
                User32.SetCursorPos(clickpoint.X, clickpoint.Y);
                User32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                User32.mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            }
        }
    }

}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

//Argument
if (ImageName01.Checked)
        {
            RunImageName1();
            RunImageNameIcon();
        }
if (ImageName02.Checked)
        {
            RunImageName2();
            RunImageNameIcon();
        }
if (ImageName03.Checked)
        {
            RunImageName3();
            RunImageNameIcon();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a background worker. When you run the computations on the same thread as the UI it creates bottlenecks which causes the UI to freeze up and sometimes do other strange stuff. Here's a link that might be useful [Using a Background Worker](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1114317/How-To-Use-BackgroundWorker-in-Csharp).

Comment: So you think using a background worker (1 for the UI and 1 to do the image detection and if statement executions) will prevent the UI from locking up? What will it do for system resources?

Comment: No, you won't need a background worker for the UI. I suggest executing the image detection code through the background worker. The UI is already running on a thread.By using the background worker you'll be able to execute the image detection code on a seperate thread. This will hopefully resolve the lagging issue.